# Hide scrollbar on web component's :host element with CSS

Tags: css, web-component, stenciljs

I've tried various ways but without a find a solution to hide the scrollbar on `:host` element selector.

I didn't had problems with Firefox and Edge:

```
:host {
  -ms-overflow-style: none;
  scrollbar-width: none;
}
```

But I struggle to find a way to doing it with Safari and Chrome:

```
:host ( ::-webkit-scrollbar ) {
  display: none;
}
```

I've tried various ways without solving the issue:

```
::-webkit-scrollbar,
*::-webkit-scrollbar,
:host( .host-selector::-webkit-scrollbar ),
:host ( [::-webkit-scrollbar] ),
:host ::-webkit-scrollbar,
:host::-webkit-scrollbar {
  display: none;
}
```

Does anyone knows how to do it right?

Comment: [This](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_hide_scrollbars.asp) should help under the hide scrollbars but keep functionality section

Comment: Yeah, I know how it works, but it doesn't work on `:host` element

Comment: I thought `:host( .host-selector::-webkit-scrollbar )` or `:host::-webkit-scrollbar` did the trick, but it doesn't